# How to extract the attributes from a node in a json dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary which contains the following json elements.

```
myjsonDictionary = \
{
  "Teams": {
    "TeamA": {
      "@oid": "123.0.0.1",
      "dataRequestList": {
        "state": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@oid": "2"
        }
      },
      "TeamSub": {
        "@oid": "3",
        "dataRequestList": {
          "state": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@oid": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    },

   # ....many nested layers
  }
}
```

I have the following issue and am currently very confused on how to solve this problem.
I want to be able to parse this dictionary and get the concatenation of the "@oid" value and the respective "@oid" when I request the "key" such as "TeamA" or "TeamSub".

I have a function which takes in the gettheiDLevelConcatoid(myjsonDictionary, key).

I can call this function like this:

```
gettheiDLevelConcatoid(myjsonDictionary, key) where "key" is like "TeamA"
```

And the expected output should be "123.0.0.1.2". Note the 2 appended to the 123.0.0.1.

```
gettheiDLevelConcatoid(myjsonDictionary, key) where "key" is like TeamSub
Output is "123.0.0.1.3.2". Note the "3.2" added to the "123.0.0.1".
```

My current implementation:

```
def gettheiDLevelConcatoid(myjsonDictionary, key)
   for item in myjsonDictionary:
       if (item == key):
        #not sure what to do
```

I am so lost on how to implement a generic method or approach for this.

Comment: post your current function body, have you already tried simple traversal?

Comment: you *lost on how to implement a generic method or approach* ? - start with simple loop over `Teams`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I look over the dictionary but I am unsure on how to access these attributes. I am not sure if there are simple methods or in built functions which could ease the traversal. Added my code which I have as of now.

Comment: how deep a searched `key` could be?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Please look at the update made to the question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I could for instance have another TeamSub node nest inside "teamSub" node with a different "@oid" and thus would return a string "123.0.0.1" concatenate with the "3" and the "@oid" of that subnode.

Comment: would subsequent teams always have a suffix `Sub` in their key name?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The Key could be of any string, The TeamsSub is just an example here.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197278/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-romanperekhrest).

Answer (score 1):

With recursive traversal for specific keys:

```
def get_team_idlvel_oid_pair(d, search_key):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k.startswith('Team'):
            if k == search_key:
                return '{}{}.{}'.format(d['@oid'] + '.' if '@oid' in d else '',
                                        v['@oid'], v['dataRequestList']['state']['@oid'])
            elif any(k.startswith('Team') for k_ in v):
                return get_team_idlvel_oid_pair(v, search_key)


print(get_team_idlvel_oid_pair(myjsonDictionary['Teams'], 'TeamA'))
print(get_team_idlvel_oid_pair(myjsonDictionary['Teams'], 'TeamSub'))
```

Sample output:

```
123.0.0.1.2
123.0.0.1.3.2
```

Comment: Is it possible to make ```if k.startswith('Team'):``` more generic as it could be some other string other than "Team".

Comment: @LauraSmith, if it's not related to conceptual key names, than you would have to check for `'@oid'`, `'dataRequestList']['state']` keys in every dictionary, which is more bothering

Comment: Not sure if you get what I mean. In the call to the get_team_idlvel_oid_pair, can I call is by ```get_team_idlvel_oid_pair(myjsonDictionary, "TeamA") rather than the one you suggested and then iterate over the dictionary and just look for the "TeamA" and return the concatenated "@oid" values as stated in the question above.

Comment: I tried to modify your code per my approach as stated in the previous comment but I am unable to access the nested nodes and only the outer level nodes

Comment: Please do let me know if you have updates for me. Any